# Error Plotting Confusion matrix from Sklearn

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the sklearn confusion matrix class to plot a confusion matrix.

Here's the code I used:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, plot_confusion_matrix

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

disp = plot_confusion_matrix(self.g_cv.best_estimator_ , self.test_X, self.test_Y,
                                 cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

        plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
        plt.plot(disp)
```

This is based on this example on Sklearn website:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix.html

However I get an error when this is called.

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'ConfusionMatrixDisplay'
```

It does plot it but also throws this error. Is there something wrong in the return object which is being plotted?

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised when trying to plot the ConfusionMatrixDisplay-object that`disp = plot_confusion_matrix(...` returns. It is meant to create a plot right away.

It is sufficient to use `plt.show()`, rather than `plt.plot(disp)`. [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) expects two arrays as input.

Either you can plot the confusion matrix right away with

```py
disp = plot_confusion_matrix(self.g_cv.best_estimator_ , self.test_X, self.test_Y, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.show()
```

or you create it first and then display it

```py
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(self.g_cv.best_estimator_ , self.test_X, self.test_Y)
disp = disp.plot(cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.show()
```